# phpMyAdmin error: Cannot access browser storage

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, iceweasel

The full text of the phpMyAdmin complaint is ...

> There was a problem accessing your browser storage, some features may not work properly for you. It is likely that the browser doesn't support storage or the quota limit has been reached. In Firefox, corrupted storage can also cause such a problem, clearing your "Offline Website Data" might help. In Safari, such problem is commonly caused by "Private Mode Browsing". '

And it shows up every time I do anything at all in phpMyAdmin. I've tried emptying the cache and local storage - which was empty anyway - but no joy there. I don't find that I have disabled local storage anywhere.

I've just installed phpMyAdmin, working against a local MySQL installation. Seems to work ok ... but I get the complaint on every single thing I do in phpMyAdmin.

While I'm here let me ask about the debian-sys-maint user with all privileges on the MySQL installation. I certainly didn't create that. I don't see a way to delete it either.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry, Jay. phpoMyAdmin 4.5.5.1 (up to date),

Comment: Got away from me there debian jessie,  iceweasel 38.7.0, phpMyAdmin 4.5.5.1 (up to date), nginx /1.6.2, php 5.6.17-0+deb8u1,  mysqli.so

Comment: Which *browser* are you using?

Comment: iceweasel 38.7.0 ... it's what debian has to term firefox due to some restrictions set up by mozzila with which they are unwilling to comply.

Comment: I can at least help with thee "debian-sys-maint" user; this is created by Debian for system maintenance. Don't modify it, and don't worry about it since it's supposed to be there.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue, and it was caused by Cookies being turned off. So turning Cookies back on solved this issue for me.

Comment: Had same issue on Firefox. Turned out it was due to me having [Privacy Settings](http://firefox.add0n.com/privacy-settings.html) add on set to max. Reduced the privacy level, fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the root cause of this error was (maybe an unfortunate Firefox crash) but getting rid of persistent site-related storage from my Firefox profile solved this for me.

Open your profile folder and get rid of the following:

```
places.sqlite
places.sqlite-shm
places.sqlite-wal
storage/
webappsstore.sqlite
webappsstore.sqlite-shm
webappsstore.sqlite-wal
```

On Mac OS X you can find your profile folder as follows.
In terminal type the command:

```
open ~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/
```

Then look for the current profile folder, which looks something like `86fdt4d.default`

NOTE: by removing these files you will remove all of your site visits (history) and offline web app data so make really sure that you are not deleting any essential data before continuing...

Answer (score 0):

Try to completely un-install Firefox

`sudo apt-get purge firefox`

Check in your home that folder `/.mozilla` does not exist (*otherwise delete it*) & re-install Firefox.